# How to find MAF application version?

Tags: java, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am curious to know that, how to find the `Oracle MAF` application version.

Since I have installed `maf-2.1200.20150423-1326-RELEASE.zip` in `JDeveloper` I got to know the installed version as `2.1.2.0.0`.

Is there any other way to find version through JDeveloper or any configuration file of the MAF application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @User404 suggested, MAF version can be find out using following steps.

<kbd>JDeveloper</kbd> --> <kbd>Help</kbd> --> <kbd>About</kbd> --> <kbd>Extensions</kbd> then you could find the extension named **`Mobile Application Framework`** with version. As shown in below image,

[image]

Hope, it might be helpful to future user.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what version of MAF is installed in your JDeveloper.
`JDeveloper` > `Help` > `About` > `Extensions` --> here you should see the MAF extension (+ version) which is currently installed.

If you open a MAF application in JDeveloper it will automatically (you should get a wizard) migrate it to your current MAF version.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.!!